# Pattern matching & capture a list of words in lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

Using lua pattern-matching, I would like to match and capture "/egg/" or "/spam/" words

**Expected string.find(haystack, pattern) results:**

```
"/spam/"    -> captures "spam"
"/egg/"     -> captures "egg"
"/spamegg/" -> returns nil and captures nothing
"/foo/"     -> returns nil and captures nothing
```

I know how to match either "egg" or "spam" but could not find a way to expresse the logical OR (though it seems vory simple).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical 'or' in Lua patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462370/logical-or-in-lua-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua patterns do not support OR.

Comment: Aw… thanks for the info. So at last, my "solution" is to use twice string.find().