# Best scripting language for cross compiling to ARM

Tags: scripting, embedded, arm

I am looking for the **best** scripting language interpreter for cross compiling to an ARM processor.  Here are the requirements for "best":

- **Its small**.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to decide which parts of the language and "standard" libraries that are supported. (For instance: file system, nah don't want that.  Floating point math, nope don't want that either.)
- **Its easy**.  Ideally, I'd like some documentation/tutorial/examples on how to do the cross-compile.

The goal: I'm writing a small, simple web server in an embedded ARM device and I'd like to do some string processing easily. The code is currently written in `C`.

I'd like the server and system-level code to be in `C`. I'd like to write the web "application" in a scripting language. The language features I'm most interested in are:

- built-in string support
- built-in regex support
- built-in map support (i.e key-value pairs object)

I'd like the "best" to come from the following list: `Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua`.  But I would be open to other language suggestions.

Comment: "scripting languages", at least among the ones you mentioned, don't need to be cross compiled, or compiled at all.

ARM is a pretty powerful platform, and won't represent much of a constraint on your choice of languages;  You should probably select a platform that suits your development process and experience"scripting languages", at least among the ones you mentioned, don't need to be cross compiled, or compiled at all.  ARM is a pretty powerful platform, and won't constrain your choice of languages;  You should probably select a platform that suits your development process and experience.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post.  I meant "scripting language interpreter", not "scripting language".  For instance, I would like to do the following in C:  MyAwesomeInterpreter(my_awesome_script_char_array);

Comment: Ahh, so you want to know how to use those languages on arm.  In each case, however you've been cross compiling your C is still valid, since each of those languages are in C.  If you are hosting on linux, most distros that support arm already support those languages in their package repositories.

Comment: Hi, this is my "problem", not hosted on linux.  No OS, no RTOS.  BTW, I already know Perl, Python, Ruby (which is why I listed them).  I've read Lua is small and powerful for embedding in applications (although not necessarily embedded applications), so I also put it on the list.  Ideally, a link to "here is how to compile language X for ARM" would be ideal :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html).

> Lua is distributed in a small package and builds out-of-the-box in all
>   platforms that have an ANSI/ISO C compiler. Lua runs on all flavors of
>   Unix and Windows, and also on mobile devices (such as handheld
>   computers and cell phones that use BREW, Symbian, Pocket PC, etc.) and
>   embedded microprocessors (such as ARM and Rabbit) for applications
>   like Lego MindStorms.

- [Pattern matching in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693334/lua-pattern-matching-vs-regular-expressions)
- [Lua tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29#Tables) should meet your map requirement.
- [Lua string manipulation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4)

[Lua compared to Python](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaVersusPython)

(Note: I really like Python and for general purpose scriping would prefer it to Lua *but* in terms of portability and performance on embedded processors I'd lean towards Lua).

Comment: Thank you for the informative links.  ATM, Lua is the winner of this poll.

Comment: @Josh, you should look more specifically at eLua (http://www.eluaproject.net/) that supports ARM7, ARM9, Cortex-M3 (http://wiki.eluaproject.net/Boards).