# Lua string.match uses irregular regular expressions?

Tags: regex, lua

I'm curious why this doesn't work, and need to know why/how to work around it; I'm trying to detect whether some input is a question, I'm pretty sure string.match is what I need, but:

`print(string.match("how much wood?", "(how|who|what|where|why|when).*\\?"))`

returns nil. I'm [pretty sure Lua's string.match uses regular expressions](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) to find matches in a string, as I've used wildcards (.) before with success, but maybe I don't understand all the mechanics? Does Lua require special delimiters in its string functions? I've tested my regular expression [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), so if Lua used regular regular expressions, it seems like the above code would return `"how much wood?"`.

Can any of you tell me what I'm doing wrong, what I mean to do, or point me to a good reference where I can get comprehensive information about how Lua's string manipulation functions utilize regular expressions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lua doesn't use regex. Lua uses [Patterns](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), which look similar but match different input.

`.*` will also consume the last `?` of the input, so it fails on `\\?`. The question mark should be excluded. Special characters are escaped with `%`.

```
"how[^?]*%?"
```

As Omri Barel said, there's no alternation operator. You probably need to use multiple patterns, one for each alternative word at the beginning of the sentence. Or you could use a library that supports regex like expressions.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think it really confused me because patterns look a lot like regex, but a little different all the same.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1), patterns don't support alternation.

So while `"how.*"` works, `"(how|what).*"` doesnt.

And kapep is right about the question mark being swallowed by the `.*`.

There's a related question: [Lua pattern matching vs. regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693334/lua-pattern-matching-vs-regular-expressions).

Answer (score -1):

As they have already answered before, it is because the patterns in lua are different from the Regex in other languages, but if you have not yet managed to get a good pattern that does all the work, you can try this simple function:

```
local function capture_answer(text)
  local text = text:lower()
  local pattern = '([how]?[who]?[what]?[where]?[why]?[when]?[would]?.+%?)'
  for capture in string.gmatch(text, pattern) do
    return capture
  end
end

print(capture_answer("how much wood?"))
```

> `Output: how much wood?`

That function will also help you if you want to find a question in a larger text string

Ex.

```
print(capture_answer("Who is the best football player in the world?\nWho are your best friends?\nWho is that strange guy over there?\nWhy do we need a nanny?\nWhy are they always late?\nWhy does he complain all the time?\nHow do you cook lasagna?\nHow does he know the answer?\nHow can I learn English quickly?"))
```

> ```
> Output:  
> who is the best football player in the world? 
> who are your best friends? 
> who is that strange guy over there? 
> why do we need a nanny? 
> why are they always late? 
> why does he complain all the time?
> how do you cook lasagna? 
> how does he know the answer? 
> how can i learn english quickly?
> ```

Comment: You're not capturing words, you're capturing ranges. Letters H-O-W or nothing, again same three letters or or nothing (e.g. zero or one time), etc, then whole bunch of anything and "?". Your function captures ANYTHING that ends with? Try `print(capture_answer("omgwtflol? extra"))` and get `omgwtflol?` back.