# What is the alternation operator in Lua patterns?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

In regex, `|` is used for alternation. What is the corresponding character in Lua patterns?

Comment: See also [Lua string.match uses irregular regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138189/lua-string-match-uses-irregular-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, note that Lua [patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) are not regular expressions; they are their own simpler matching language (with different benefits and drawbacks).

Per the specification I've linked to above, and per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696469/405017), there is no alternation operator in a Lua pattern. To get this functionality you'll need to use a more powerful Lua construct (like [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) or a [Lua Regex Library](http://rrthomas.github.com/lrexlib/)).

Comment: I will complement this perfectly good answer by saying that sometimes you can get away with not using LPEG or Lua Regex - a plain ´or´ might do the trick: `if s:match(a) or s:match(b) then ...`

Comment: often you can also get away with a more general match and switch on the result...: `local word = s:match("%w+") if word =="foo" or word == "bar" then.... else ....... end`

Comment: I came to this question from the perspective of Arduino Regexp (which is based on Lua patterns). I was hoping this answer would include a work-around that I could port.

Answer (score 3):

Lua does not have alternations in patterns you cannot use (`test1`|`test2`). You can only choose between multiple characters like `[abcd]` will match `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`.

Answer (score -5):

Another workaround is: Instead of:

> apple|orange

Write:

> [ao][pr][pa][ln][eg]

Explanation: match alternate letters from each word. voila!

Comment: That would match `arplg` as well.