# Lua function to output matched strings in SciTE

Tags: lua, scintilla, scite

I know how to output lines of matched strings (result from find command) by simply using `editor:MarkerNext()`:

```
function print_marked_lines()

    local ml = 0
    local lines = {}

    while true do
        ml = editor:MarkerNext(ml, 2)
        if (ml == -1) then break end
        table.insert(lines, (editor:GetLine(ml)))
        ml = ml + 1
    end

    local text = table.concat(lines)
    print(text)

end
```

What I don't know is how to output only matched strings (not whole line as with posted snippet). I assume there is solution as matched strings are highlighted and must have some property which would allow extracting them, but I guess Scintilla knowledge is needed as I couldn't find any reference in provided SciTE bindings.

Example screenshot for find/match all regex pattern "I \w+":

[image]

I want to output (print to output pane) all highlighted string parts

Answer (score 1):

@theta, nasty question (at least it was for me) `:)`

The problem is that in the Scite GUI "find/replace" dialog, you use one regex syntax for match patterns, with backslash (say, `\s`); while in Scite `lua` functions, you use a different syntax for patterns, with percent sign (correspondingly, `%s`) - see my posting in  [Lua pattern matching vs. regular expressions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411990/277826). From there, you have these two references:

- [SciTE Regular Expressions](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) - regex pattern syntax for use in Scite GUI "Find/Replace" dialogs

  - *Note, here they use `\l` as a stand-in for actual character classes (like `\w` and others)!*
- [lua-users wiki: Patterns Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) - regex pattern syntax for use within `lua` extension scripts in Scite

  - *Note, here the `%l` class actually exists, meaning lowercase characters (in addition to `%w` and others)!*
  - Full documentation of pattern syntax for character classes: [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual: 5.4.1 - Patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

Correspondingly, code for your function ("*to output (print to output pane) all highlighted string parts*") would be:

```
function print_marked_lines()

  local sel = editor:GetSelText()

  for mymatch in sel:gmatch"I %w+" do -- note; a regex match!
    print(mymatch)
  end

end
```

Outputs this in output pane from your example text:

```
I don
I assume
I guess
I couldn
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Unfortunately that would imply knowledge in yet another pattern syntax - Lua's. IMHO `editor:findtext(regex)` should be used and matched lines be additionally parsed for scintilla indicators - that was something I didn't know how to do. OTOH, some time after my question, SciTE introduced *strip dialog* which makes many things easily possible: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTELua.html (described at the bottom of the page). For example here is screenshot of wrapping `sh` and using `grep` to do above job: http://i.imgur.com/XogF9.png

Comment: Now reading linked page, seems like `editor:match(text, [flags])` generator is the easiest way to go